# How to get uploaded image url in sails js

Tags: sails.js

I am successfully able to upload files. But i need to get the url.
For eg: localhost:1337/images/image.jpg
I have tried to do this but not successful yet

Sails version i am using is 1.2.3

Here is my code for upload

```
try{
   var uploadFile = req.file('images');
   uploadFile.upload({ dirname: '../../assets/images' }, function onUploadComplete(err, files) {
      if (err) 
          return res.serverError(err);
      return res.json({ status: 200, file: files });
   });
}catch(err){
    return res.serverError(err);
}
```

localhost:1337/images/image.jpg
This says Not Found

Comment: After upload i get this response

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [sails-hook-uploads](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-uploads)   and check out `https://github.com/mikermcneil/ration`
Check this file too
https://github.com/mikermcneil/ration/blob/master/api/controllers/things/upload-thing.js